# Windows 10 64bit Office 2016 64bit - registry key

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, microsoft-office, windows-registry

I am using OCS Inventory and there is a plugin to retrieve office cd-key and other informations.

It works well with office 2007/10/13 and also 16 but pro version.

But the main question:

(Office '13)
When I typed regedit in RUN dialog box I am going to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Registration
```

and there is office GUID and I can see positions like DigitalProductId/ProductId/Product Name etc..

But I am looking for same thing in registry had installed Office 2016 Home&Businnes.

Where Microsoft hide this key in registry?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: I am just looking for key: DigitalProductID of my Office 2016 in registry.

Comment: The location is in the identical location, except Office 2013 is "Office 15: and Office 2016 would be Office 16 if I am not mistaken.  In other words, your DigitalProductID, is located in the registry.

Comment: This is a problem... In this location (16) there isn't

Comment: Which method was used to obtain and  install Office 2016 H&B?

Comment: iso install 2016 64bit then activated by used key from box

Comment: I am 100% there should be a `..\Microsoft\Office\16.0\` registry key.  It does not matter you have `Office 2016 Home and Business` instead of `Office 2016 Professional`

Comment: heh missing directory like Registration